# Check inserted successful doing mysqli_query in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a insert query within a loop, how do I check if the operation is done or succeed?

```
foreach ($_POST['players'] as $value) {
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO contactphone(player_id, player_number) VALUES('$value['player_id']','$value['player_number']')");
}
```

Normally for single insert, I will do `mysqli_insert_id` but in this case I'm not sure.

Comment: A single query can insert multiple rows and then you can check the affected rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the query execution line in an if statement. I also added an error check line which echoes the error message for the current instance,  should the query not be executed successfully.

```
foreach ($_POST['players'] as $value) {
if(mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO contactphone(player_id, player_number) VALUES('$value['player_id']','$value['player_number']')") === false){
echo 'error.. The error is '. mysqli_error($conn);
}
}
```